# How to detect if a bash script is already running, considering its arguments

Tags: linux, bash

Sorry for my poor english ;)

I need to check if a script is already running or not. I don't want to use a lock file, as it can be tricky (ie: if my script wrote a lock file, but crashed, I will consider it as running).
I also need to take parameters into account. ie:
test.sh 123
should be considered as a different process than
test.sh 456

I tried this :

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "inside test.sh, script name with arguments: $0 +$*$"

echo "  simple pgrep on script name with arguments:"
pgrep -f "$0 +$*$"

echo "  counting simple pgrep on script name with arguments with wc -l"
echo $(pgrep -f "$0 +$*$" | wc -l)

echo "  counting pgrep echo result with wc -w"
processes=$(pgrep -f "$0 +$*$")
nbProcesses=$(echo $processes | wc -w)
echo $nbProcesses

sleep 300
```

When I try, I get this result:

```
[frederic.charrier@charrier tmp]$ /tmp/test.sh 123
inside test.sh, script name with arguments: /tmp/test.sh +123$
  simple pgrep on script name with arguments:
123976
  counting simple pgrep on script name with arguments with wc -l
2
  counting pgrep echo result with wc -w
1
^Z
[1]+  Stoppé                 /tmp/test.sh 123
[frederic.charrier@charrier tmp]$ /tmp/test.sh 123
inside test.sh, script name with arguments: /tmp/test.sh +123$
  simple pgrep on script name with arguments:
123976
124029
  counting simple pgrep on script name with arguments with wc -l
3
  counting pgrep echo result with wc -w
2
```

My questions are:

- when I run the script the first time, it's running once. So pgrep is returning only one result: 123976, which is fine. But why a "wc -l" on 123976 is returning 2?
- when I run the script a second time, I get the same strange behavior: pgrep returns the correct result, pgrep | wc -l returns something wrong, and "echo pgrep ... | wc -w" returns the correct result. Why?

Comment: Is it possible the pgrep command is finding itself in addition to the command you're looking for? You can check by using `ps` and you can avoid it by using `| grep -v grep` to exclude the PIDs from grep commands.

Comment: This seems to be specific to Linux, by the way. I cannot reproduce on macOS. Whether the issue is with `pgrep` or `wc`, I cannot tell.

Comment: If you can't find the solution you are looking for in the 54 answers in the two linked questions, please explain why and your question can be considered for reopening.

Comment: Sorry if it sounds as duplicated, but I wanted to avoid a "flock" solution. Anyway, everything is fine, as @kamilcuk answer helped me to understand the "two processes" count after a substitution :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to detect if a bash script is already running

If you are aware of the drawbacks of your method, using `pgrep` looks fine. Note that both `$0` and `$*` can have regex-syntax stuff in them, you have to escape them first, and I think I would also do `pgrep -f "^$0...` to match it from the beginning.

> why a "wc -l" on 123976 is returning 2?

Because command substitution `$(..)` spawns a subshell, so there are two shells running, when `pgrep` is executed.

Overall, `echo $(cmd)` is an antipattern. Just run it `cmd`.

In some cases, like when there is single one command inside command substitution, bash optimizes and replaces (`exec`) the subshell with the command itself, effectively eliminating the subshell. This is an optimization. That's why `processes=$(pgrep ..)` returns 1.

> Why?

There is one more process running.

Comment: But `echo $(pgrep ...)` still only outputs a single process ID.